# How to create this animation?

Tags: android

I want to do this animation, when switching between 2 activities:

[image]

--

[image]

--

[image]

any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here the answer:

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

                ViewFlipper flipper = findViewById(R.id.flipper);
                flipper.setOnTouchListener(this);
}

private void myOnTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        switch (event.getAction()) {

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            mDragged = true;
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            mDragged = false;
            mXbefore = event.getX();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

            if(mDragged){
                vf = (ViewFlipper) v;
                mXafter = event.getX();

                if(mXafter > mXbefore){
                    vf.setInAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.right_to_left_in));
                    vf.setOutAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.right_to_left_out));
                    vf.showNext();
                }else{
                    vf.setInAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.left_to_right_in));
                    vf.setOutAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.left_to_right_out));
                    vf.showPrevious();
                }
            }

            mDragged = false;
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
```

main.xml:

```
<ViewFLipper id="@+id/flipper">
         <YourLayout />
          <YourLayout />
</ViewFlipper>
```

---

right_to_left_in.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate 
        android:fromXDelta="-100%p" 
        android:toXDelta="0%p" 
        android:duration="500"/>
    <alpha android:fromAlpha="0.0" android:toAlpha="1.0" android:duration="500" />
</set>
```

---

right_to_left_out.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate 
        android:fromXDelta="100%p" 
        android:toXDelta="200%p" 
        android:duration="500"/>
    <alpha android:fromAlpha="0.0" android:toAlpha="1.0" android:duration="500" />
</set>
```

---

left_to_right_in.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate 
        android:fromXDelta="100%p" 
        android:toXDelta="0" 
        android:duration="500"/>
    <alpha android:fromAlpha="0.0" android:toAlpha="1.0" android:duration="500" />
</set>
```

---

left_to_right_out_xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate 
        android:fromXDelta="0%p" 
        android:toXDelta="-100%p" 
        android:duration="500"/>
    <alpha android:fromAlpha="1.0" android:toAlpha="0.0" android:duration="500" />
</set>
```

Answer (score 1):

those 2 methods are realy usefull to solve the issue quikly:

```
Animation slide_out_left = AnimationUtils.makeOutAnimation(getActivity(),false);
Animation slide_in_right = AnimationUtils.makeInAnimation(getActivity(), true);

Animation slide_out_right = AnimationUtils.makeOutAnimation(getActivity(),true);
Animation slide_in_left = AnimationUtils.makeInAnimation(getActivity(), false);
```

[here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/AnimationUtils.html#makeInAnimation%28android.content.Context,%20boolean%29) is the doc of the methods, as you'll see the second parameter is a flag to choose the side.

The result is similar to what [Rodrigo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/740394/rodrigo) wrote before but it take 2 lines of code and dosen't require the definition of custom animation.